# ps/pgrep cannot find running script missing #!/bin/bash

Tags: linux, shell

I found ps or pgrep cannot find running script without "#!/bin/bash"

Here is a sample.sh:

```
while true
do
    echo $(date)                                                                                                                                                         
done
```

start the script (ubuntu 18.04, Linux version 4.15.0-101-generic):

```
$echo $BASH
/bin/bash
./sample.sh
```

open another terminal, ps only find the command grep

```
$ps -aux |grep sample.sh
16887  0.0  0.0  16184  1008 pts/4    S+   07:12   0:00 grep --color=auto sample
```

pgrep find nothing

```
$pgrep sample
$
```

But if I add "#!/bin/bash" to sample.sh, everything works now:

```
#!/bin/bash      <-----add this line                                                                                                                                                        
while true
do
    echo $(date)
done
```

I am wondering why.

Comment: I guess that depends on the bash version you have, because I can't get `sample.sh`'s PID either way with bash 5.0.11. But if I put `printf 'boogaloo' > /proc/self/comm` in `sample.sh`'s first line, I can get its PID by `pgrep boogaloo`.

Comment: @camino : One difference of course is that without a #! line, the script will be run by `sh` , but this still does not explain for me the differnce. What happens if you start the script explicitly by `sh sample.sh`, compared to `bash sample.sh`?

Comment: @user1934428 sh sample.sh, ps aux|grep sample.sh works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the second of your cases, namely where you *do* have `#!/bin/bash`, because it is actually the easier one to deal with first.

### With the `#!/bin/bash`

When you execute a script which starts with `#!/path/to/interpreter`, the Linux kernel will understand this syntax and will invoke the specified interpreter for you in the same way as if you had explicitly added `/path/to/interpreter` to the start of the command line.  So in the case of your script starting with `#!/bin/bash`, if you look using `ps ux`, you will see the command line `/bin/bash ./sample.sh`.

### Without the `#!/bin/bash`

Now turning to the other one where the `#!/bin/bash` is missing.  This case is more subtle.

A file which is neither a compiled executable nor a file starting with the `#!` line **cannot be executed by the Linux kernel at all**.  Here is an example of trying to run the `sample.sh` without the `#!/bin/bash` line from a python script:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p  = subprocess.Popen("./sample.sh")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

And to show that this is not just a python issue, here is a demonstration of exactly the same thing, but from a C program.  Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

  execl("./sample.sh", "sample.sh", NULL);

  /* exec failed if reached */
  perror("exec failed");
  return 1;  
}
```

and here is the output:

```
exec failed: Exec format error
```

So what is happening here case when you run the script is that **because you are invoking it from a bash shell**, bash is giving some fault tolerance by running the commands directly after the attempt to "exec" the script has failed.

What is happening in more detail is that:

- bash forks a subshell,
- inside the subshell it straight away does a call to the Linux kernel to "exec" your executable, and *if successful*, that would end that (subshell) process and replace it with a process running the executable
- however, the exec is *not* successful, and this means that the subshell is still running
- at that point the subshell just reads the commands inside your script and starts executing them directly.

The overall effect is very similar to the `#!/bin/bash` case, but because the subshell was just started by forking your original bash process, it has the same command line, i.e. just `bash`, without any command line argument.  If you look for this subshell in the output of `ps uxf` (a tree-like view of your processes), you will see it just as

```
bash
 \_ bash
```

whereas in the `#!/bin/bash` case you get:

```
bash
 \_ /bin/bash ./sample.sh
```